# TFS 2010 restored database, TfsJobAgent cannot connect to database

Tags: tfs, disaster-recovery

I have a Team Foundation Server 2010 setup, in which I have TFS on one server and the databases on another. Recently the server with the databases completely crashed and I had to replace it. I restored the databases from backups, and changed the web.config file for tfs to point to the new server and most everything seems to be working. I can connect to tfs, do checkouts/checkins, create work items, etc. However, I cannot queue builds, and the event log is filling up with errors saying that TfsJobAgent cannot connect to the database. I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to configure TfsJobAgent to point to my new database. The event log details are below (TCOSRV1 is the machine running tfs, not the database server). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation
>   component or extension: Date (UTC): 7/11/2013 4:55:27 PM Machine:
>   TCOSRV1 Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe Assembly:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727 Service
>   Host: Process Details: Process Name: TFSJobAgent Process Id: 3520
>   Thread Id: 5304 Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Detailed Message: There was an error during job agent execution. The
>   operation will be retried. Similar errors in the next five minutes may
>   not be logged. Exception Message: TF246017: Team Foundation Server
>   could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is
>   hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not
>   blocking communication with the server. (type
>   DatabaseConnectionException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace: at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(Int32
>   errorNumber, SqlException sqlException, SqlError sqlError) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException
>   sqlException) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException
>   ex, QueryExecutionState queryState) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(SqlException
>   ex) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType
>   executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ExtendedAttributeComponent.ReadDatabaseAttribute(String
>   attributeName) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseConnectionValidator.ValidateDatabaseInstanceStamp(String
>   configConnectionString, Guid configInstanceId) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseConnectionValidator.ValidateApplicationConfiguration(String
>   configConnectionString, Guid configInstanceId, List`1 sqlInstances,
>   String analysisInstance, String analysisDatabaseName, Boolean
>   ignoreAnalysisDatasourceUpdateErrors, Boolean autoFixConfiguration,
>   Boolean fullValidation, DatabaseVerificationDatabaseTypes
>   continueOnMissingDatabaseTypes) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ApplicationServiceHost..ctor(Guid
>   instanceId, String connectionString, String physicalDirectory, String
>   plugInDirectory, String virtualDirectory, Boolean
>   failOnInvalidConfiguration) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobApplication.SetupInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobServiceUtil.RetryOperationsUntilSuccessful(RetryOperations
>   operations)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified) (type SqlException) SQL Exception Class: 20
>   SQL Exception Number: -1 SQL Exception Procedure: SQL Exception Line
>   Number: 0 SQL Exception Server: SQL Exception State: 0 SQL Error(s):
>
> Exception Data Dictionary: HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
>   HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer HelpLink.EvtID = -1 HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl
>   = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
>
> Exception Stack Trace: at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType
>   executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restoring to a new Data Tier (as it's called when you move between servers) needs to follow a quite extensive process to ensure that all settings are properly updated. The procedure would be the same for the process you'd use to migrate from one SQL Server to another.

The full process is explained here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404869(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'll give this as the answer, being as how this is probably what I should have done.  I ended up just re-installing tfs completely, and then restoring the project collections.  Luckily my setup isn't that involved (no sharepoint or reporting services).  Thanks.